# How to change the label for size options in Shopify?

Tags: label, size, shopify, product

In a Shopify store on the page of product I have options to choose the size of the product.

Now the label for these options shows "`The name of product`" `+ word "Size`" - 
Example:
`"Shoe Size"`.

How can I change this label to just "`Size`"?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We need more information in order to help you. We need to see the code of the section in order to understand how was this coded.

Comment: Heya Denys!  If you go to this product in your Shopify admin, you should see that there are two option dimensions defined.  I'm guessing that the option was set up as "Shoe Size" - if I'm right, you can edit the product's options to rename that to be simply "Size"

Comment: @drip I added a new picture with the code, probably it makes it more clear.

Comment: @DaveB from Customized I entered Product menu and about three times looked through the Theme Settings in Product. And I didn't find where I can rewrite this label from the admin panel.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like the product ID is 1442529044055 from your screenshot. If you go to [yourstore].myshopify.com/admin/products/1442529044055, you should see a section under Images labelled **Variants**.  At the top of this area, there should be three links: Reorder Variants, Edit options, and Add Variant.  If you click Edit Options, you should be able to rename the option dimensions of the product in question.  Let me know if this gets you moving in the right direction.

Comment: @DaveB, yes, you are right, that's it!!) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help!  I copied my comments to an answer so that you can mark this one solved to help anyone else searching for a solution if they're in a similar situation :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to this product in your Shopify admin, you should see that there are two option dimensions defined. I'm guessing that the option was set up as "Shoe Size" - if I'm right, you can edit the product's options to rename that to be simply "Size"

You'll need to find the product in your Shopify admin to make the change.  It looks like the product ID is 1442529044055 from your screenshot, so the direct link to that product's admin page is `[yourstore].myshopify.com/admin/products/1442529044055`. You should see a section under Images labelled Variants. At the top of this area, there should be three links: Reorder Variants, Edit options, and Add Variant. If you click Edit Options, you should be able to rename the option dimensions of the product in question.

Let me know if this gets you moving in the right direction!